# ViewController's layout is smaller/enlarged on different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I just submitted my 1st app to to the app store and am nervous that Apple will reject it due to my screen layout being off for certain devices.

[image: iPhone 6 ViewController]

[image: iPhone 5 ViewController]

Notice that the iPhone 6's ViewController's Label is moved upward and the iPhone 5's ViewController's Label is moved downward.

What steps do I need to take to make both ViewControllers look identical? regardless of screen size

Comment: Your gonna have to set up some constraints to get it scaling properly.

Comment: Apple won't reject it if it looks different on different phone sizes. However, they will reject it if your layout causes text or images to be cut off on different phones. You just need to make sure that the formatting is appropriate for each size, not necessarily identical

Comment: @BenjaminLowry I noticed it looked cut off a little on the iPhone 4 only, I hope they don't care about that because they would want people to buy their newer phones anyways

Comment: Well if it is cut off, you might want to either set up some more sophisticated constraints to make it similar for each phone model, or develop your app for iOS 10 which would prevent iPhone 4/4s users from using your app. If you develop for iOS 9 or lower, the App Store may reject the app if it is cut off. Then again, they could miss it. It's up to you how careful you want to be.